# Upstart Help: Change Ubuntu 10.04 Service Boot Order

Tags: linux, boot, services, ordering, upstart

I am having an issue with the order in which services start up in Ubuntu 10.04.  My workstations are configured to use `winbind` to connect to my Domain Controller for authentication.

The problem is that the `gdm` login screen will appear before the network interfaces have come up.  This causes a problem, as clients cannot log in since the computer can't yet talk to the domain server.

Is there a way to delay the startup order of `gdm` such that it only appears after the network interfaces have been configured?

Ubuntu is now using `upstart`, and unfortunately, there is no GUI to configure it and the documentation is terrible.  I really don't know where to start with it.

Comment: For documentation you can do worse than look at [`man init`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/init.8.html) and [`man 5 init`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man5/init.5.html) - the latter documents the `/etc/init/*.conf` file format. It may not give you the big picture of course ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In */etc/init/gdm.conf* add the line

```
and net-device-up IFACE=eth0
```

to the *start on* statement (replace eth0 with the interface you need). It should look like

```
start on (filesystem
          and net-device-up IFACE=eth0
          and started dbus
          and (graphics-device-added fb0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
               or drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
               or stopped udevtrigger))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful.

One question though: where are the `upstart` "modules" defined?  For example, where is `net-device-up`, or `filesystem` defined?  I would also like to alter my script to wait for `winbind` to connect to the domain controller.

Comment: Events can be emitted in .conf files using the "emits" statement (like the "filesystem" event in  mountall.conf) or by external programs using DBus (net-device-up is AFAIK emitted by upstart-udev-bridge; you can use initctl to emit events from the command line).